# Mysql query result and str_replace

Tags: php, mysqli, str-replace

I have the following code:

```php
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0); 

$source = ('Adam has a cat');
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'test') or die ('Not connect to MySQL.<br />Error: '.mysqli_error());
echo "Connect OK!<br />";
$db -> query("SET CHARSET utf8");
$db -> query("SET NAMES 'UTF-8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'");
$replace= "SELECT * FROM `replace`";
                $qr = $db->query($replace);
                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(qr))
            {
                $text= str_replace(($data['search']),($data['replace_new']),$source);
            }

echo ($text);

?>
```

I have in database two columns

```
search|replace_new
```

And data in this columns:

```
Adam|John
cat|dog
```

I want connect to db and replace "Adam has a cat" to "John has a dog".

When i run this code only change Adam to John but cat is no change.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated!
Sorry for my english.

Comment: You are replacing values in the original string over and over.  `$text` should be an argument to `str_replace()`.

Comment: I change `{
                $source= str_replace(($data['search']),($data['replace_new']),$text);
            }

echo ($source);` but i have Undefined variable $tekst. I have no idea. Sorry i'm newbie in php.

Answer (score 0):

Oki it's work ;) I invented... ;)

```php
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0); 

$source = ('Adam has a cat');
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'test') or die ('Not connect to MySQL.<br />Error: '.mysqli_error());
echo "Connect OK!<br />";
$db -> query("SET CHARSET utf8");
$db -> query("SET NAMES 'UTF-8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'");
$replace= "SELECT * FROM `replace`";
                $qr = $db->query($replace);
                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(qr))
            {
                $source= str_replace(($data['search']),($data['replace_new']),$source);
            }

echo ($source);

?>
```